# Stalk of the direct image of a locally free sheaf

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, limits-colimits, coherent-sheaves

Suppose $C$ is an irreducible algebraic curve, $U \subset C$ is an open subset, $M$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of rank $\mathrm{n}$. Let $j : U \rightarrow C$ be the open embedding, I want to calculate $(j_{*}M \vert_U)_p$ for $p$ a point on the boundary of $U$, and I guess it is $K_{C,p} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{C,p}} M_p$, where $\mathcal{O}_{C,p}$ is the stalk of the structure sheaf of $C$ at $p$, and $K_{C,p}$ is its quotient field. My proof works as follows, pick $p \in W \subset C$ such that $M \vert_W \simeq \mathcal{O}_X^{n}$, then
$$
(j_{*}M \vert_U)_p = \varinjlim_{V \ni p} M(U \cap V) = \varinjlim_{V \ni p, V \subset W} M(U \cap V) \simeq \varinjlim_{V \ni p, V \subset W} \mathcal{O}_W^n (U \cap V) = K_{C,p}^n \simeq K_{C,p} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{C,p}} M_p
$$
where the first equality comes from the fact that being $W$ dense it intersects every open non-empty subset, hence we can calculate the colimit on open subsets contained in $W$ and then use restriction maps; the second isomorphism comes from the choice of $W$; the third equality comes from the fact that $U \cap V$ doesn't contain $p$, hence $\mathcal{O}^n_{W}(U \cap V)$ contains $x_p^{-1}$ for each $V$, where $x_p$ is a local coordinate at $p$. Is my proof correct?

Comment: What is $p$ ? ${}$

Comment: $p$ is a point of C

Comment: Then what you write is obviously false for $p\in U$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify: $p$ is a point on the boundary of $U$ in $C$.

Comment: What you write is correct but a more canonical answer is that for $p\in C\setminus U$ we have $ (j_{*}M \vert_U)_p = M_\eta$, where $\eta$ is the generic point of $C$.

Comment: By algebraic curve I mean a ringed space which locally is like the maximal spectrum of a finitely generated reduced algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$. Hence, there is no generic point. I guess you're statement is correct when $C$ is reduced integral scheme of dimension 1. Am I right?

Comment: Your definition does not define "algebraic curve" since it does not invoke dimension one. My comment applies to any integral scheme (of any dimension),  any closed point $p$ not in $U$ and any sheaf, locally free or not.

Comment: Sorry again, yes to my definition add smooth of dimension 1. Ok, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, Federico.